# Differentiating a matrix with respect to a vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors, matrix-calculus

In multivariate linear model, I have come across the following matrix-valued function of $\beta \in \Bbb R^p$.

$$\beta \mapsto(y-X\beta)(y-X\beta)^{T}$$

where matrix $X \in \Bbb R^{n \times p}$ and vector $y \in \Bbb R^n$ are given. I have to differentiate it with respect to $\beta \in \Bbb R^p$. Can anyone please help me with how to differentiate this?

Some other examples that I have seen on this site are differentiation of $(y-X\beta)^{T}(y-X\beta)$ (which is a scalar), but here the expression is an $n×n$ matrix and I am not sure how to handle this. Also, I would appreciate some reference or reading materials on this kind of matrix-vector differentiation for beginners.

Comment: You need a 3-dimensional matrix. What you should do is differentiate each entry of the output matrix with respect to the vector input, thereby obtaining a gradient.  Then collect all $n p$ gradients in some list.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Sorry, but what is gradient and what does it mean to collect gradients in a list? May I request you to elaborate with some example?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2400103/339790) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2887550/339790) and *especially* [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2699956/339790). By "collecting gradients" I mean something like an $n \times p$ matrix where each entry is a gradient rather than a scalar. It would be a "cubical" matrix.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\e{\varepsilon}\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\bigl(#1\bigr)}
\def\vecc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$Here are two approaches to avoid the 3D-matrix (aka tensor) issue mentioned by Rodrigo.

First, note that the gradient of a vector $(b)$ with respect to
one of its components $(b_k)$ is the corresponding cartesian basis vector $(\e_k)$
$$\eqalign{
\grad{b}{b_k} &= \e_k \\
}$$
For ease of typing, I'll use $b$ instead of $\beta,\,$
and also define the vector
$$\eqalign{
z &= (Xb-y) \qiq
\grad z{b_k} &= X\e_k = x_k \\
}$$
where $x_k$ is the $k^{th}$ column of $X$.

Using this, the component-wise gradient is easy to calculate
$$\eqalign{
Q &= zz^T \\
\grad {Q}{b_k} &= zx_k^T + x_kz^T \\
}$$
Another approach is to vectorize the matrix differential
of the function
$$\eqalign{
Q &= zz^T \\
dQ &= X\,db\,z^T + z\,db^TX^T \\
\vecc{dQ} &= \BR{z\otimes X + X\otimes z}\,db \\
\grad{\vecc{Q}}b &= {z\otimes X + X\otimes z} \\
}$$
where $(\otimes)$ denotes the Kronecker product.

Or you could extend the component-wise result
to a full tensor result
$$\eqalign{
\grad {Q_{ij}}{b_k} &= z_iX_{jk} + X_{ik}z_j \\
}$$

Comment: But what I want is the differentiation with respect to $b$, not $b_k$.

Comment: @user587389 Then build a 3-dimensional matrix.

Comment: So won't it be $X$ instead of $x_k$?

Comment: @user587389 I have sent you links. Maybe you should read them.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes, I'll read them. Thank you for the links.

Answer (score 0):

The notion of differentiation in this context can come back to the meaning of the derivative as some approximated behaviour near a given point : that is, if you denote by $f$ your function,

$$ f(\beta + \varepsilon \alpha) = f(\beta) + \varepsilon f'(\beta) \cdot \alpha + o(\varepsilon) $$

so $f'(\beta)$ will be a linear operator from vectors to $n \times n$ matrices. In this case, you can do the asymptotic by yourself :

$$ f(\beta + \varepsilon \alpha) = (y - X \beta - \varepsilon X \alpha) (y - X \beta - \varepsilon X \alpha)^T \\
= (y - X \beta)(y - X \beta)^T - \varepsilon ( X \alpha (y - X \beta)^T + (y - X \beta) (X \alpha)^T ) + O(\varepsilon^2) $$

and you find :

$$ f'(\beta) : \alpha \mapsto X\alpha (y - X \beta)^T + (y - X \beta) \alpha^T X^T $$